# regex find match between certain characters and contains specific character

Tags: regex

So I have this text below:

```
#nama:sulaiman haqa#alamat:kepanjen#kelamain:L#hobi:tidur#
```

I need to find text between `:` and `#` that contains certain keyword.
 Example:

```
Search keyword: haq
result: sulaiman haqa
```

In example above, string `sulaiman haqa` fulfill the requirements: it's between `:` and `#` and also it has `haq` keyword.

I use this regular expression to find the word between `:` and `#`, but I don't know how to put the contains condition.

```
(?<=\:).*?(?=\#)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
(?<=:)[^#]*haq[^#]*(?=#)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3uKymj/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<=:)`: Lookbehind to assert that previous character is `:`
- `[^#]*`: Match 0 or more of any character that is not `#`
- `haq`: Match text `haq`
- `[^#]*`: Match 0 or more of any character that is not `#`
- `(?=#)`: Lookahead to assert that next character is `#`

Answer (score 2):

How about just this:

```
(?<=\:).*?haq.*?(?=\#)
```

You'd need to use your language's facilities to escape "haq" though in case it contained any special characters.

Comment: unless the search text could include hashes... :)

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is just fine, my guess is that you might only want to add a capturing group:

```
(?<=:)(.*haq.*?)(?=#)
```

so that to capture your desired values, and that'd likely solve the problem.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pyNwaT/1/)